# fullcalendar EventReceive Pass value when throwing an event

Tags: javascript, ajax, fullcalendar

Good afternoon. I can not pass the value in the div tag when the event is called by throw.
All Google rummaged, could not find how correctly to receive properties div
Example code below

// здесь подключил функцию дропа события  - начало
            droppable: true, // Это позволяет опускать вещи на календарь

```
        drop: function() {
            // Установлен флажок «удалить после падения»?
                      $.ajaxSetup({
                            headers: {
                                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                            }
                        });
                      // var title1 = $('.draggable').data('event', { title: 'my event' });
                      var date_start = $.fullCalendar.moment(event.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
                       var title1 = $.fullCalendar.moment(event.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
                       $.post('testhuhu', { field1: title1, field2 : date_start}, 
                            function(returnedData){
                                 alert("Данные успешно отправлены на сервер");
                        });
        },
```

Here is the code of the tag

```
<div id='wrap'>

    <div id='external-events'>
        <h4>Упражнения</h4>
        <div class='fc-event' data-event='1'>Упражение 1</div>
        <div class='fc-event' data-event='2'>Упражение 2</div>
        <div class='fc-event' data-event='3'>Упражение 3</div>
        <div class='fc-event' data-event='4'>Упражение 4</div>
        <div class='fc-event' data-event='5'>Упражение 5</div>
        <p>
            <input type='checkbox' id='drop-remove' />
            <label for='drop-remove'>remove after drop</label>
        </p>
    </div>

    <div id='calendar'></div>

    <div style='clear:both'></div>

</div>
```

How do I transfer data from div data-event = '1'
In the variable var id
Very much I ask to help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs: (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dropping/drop/) "`this` holds the DOM element that has been dropped." Therefore within the "drop" function, you can write `$(this).data("event")` which will return the data-event value for the element.

See here for a basic working demo of this: http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/585/

Comment: for me 'this' was holding the whole calendar.

Comment: @NickKovalsky you mean inside the `drop` callback? I disagree, that's not what the spec says and not what my experience is. Can you make a JSFiddle or CodePen which demonstrates this behaviour?

Comment: @NickKovalsky In fact see here: http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/585/ demonstrates that what I've said in this answer is correct: http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/585/ . I'm not sure in which conditions you were experiencing `this` representing the whole calendar, but it certainly doesn't occur in the `drop` callback. Perhaps the circumstances where you experienced this were different somehow from what I've described?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add one more data to your html for the proposed solution to work:

```
<div id='external-events'>
        <h4>Упражнения</h4>
        <div class='fc-event' data-key="key1" data-event='1'>Упражение 1</div>
        <div class='fc-event' data-key="key2" data-event='2'>Упражение 2</div>
        <div class='fc-event' data-key="key3" data-event='3'>Упражение 3</div>
        <div class='fc-event' data-key="key4" data-event='4'>Упражение 4</div>
        <div class='fc-event' data-key="key5" data-event='5'>Упражение 5</div>
        <p>
            <input type='checkbox' id='drop-remove' />
            <label for='drop-remove'>remove after drop</label>
        </p>
    </div>
```

the `data-key` will act as an intermediate id for the dropped element, generate it when building external-events in code or put them manually in your html. Btw fullCalendar will add this `key` data parameter automatically to the event, and it could be accessed with `event.key` in javascript code later.

Anyway now we can find your dropped element by `data-key` and extract its `data-event` with jquery inside the `eventReceive` function:

```
    var myDropped = $('#external-events').find('div').filter(function() {
        return $(this).data('key') === event.key;});
    var myParam = myDropped.data("event");
```